# How to get the first unique multivalue (array-notated) inputs in a form using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, jquery-selectors

I have a form like this:

```
<form>
    <select name="user_id[]"></select>
    <select name="user_id[]"></select>
    <select name="user_id[]"></select>
    <select name="user_id[]"></select>
    <select name="tag_id[]"></select>
    <select name="tag_id[]"></select>
    <select name="stack_id[]"></select>
    <!-- ... etc. -->
</form>
```

I want to get a jQuery collection consisting of the first multivalue elements by name:

```
<form>
    <select name="user_id[]"></select>   <!-- this -->
    <select name="user_id[]"></select>
    <select name="user_id[]"></select>
    <select name="user_id[]"></select>
    <select name="tag_id[]"></select>    <!-- this -->
    <select name="tag_id[]"></select>    
    <select name="stack_id[]"></select>  <!-- this -->
    <!-- ... etc. -->
</form>
```

I've started with `$('[name$="[]"]')` but I'm stuck from there.  Is there a simple selector method or would I have to select them all and filter the ones I want?

Comment: *Secondly...* what is the correct term for input elements notated as such: `id[]`?  I'll edit my question to be clearer when someone can tell me.

Comment: I 'm not sure if there's a specific term for elements named this way, but it doesn't really matter. The core of the question applies to all elements that have the same name, no matter if it ends with square brackets or not.

Comment: A _POST_ form with input elements `<input name="foo" value="bar"/><input name="foo" value="baz"/>` will still _POST_ two _foo_ values _bar_ and _baz_, it's just the server will only choose one of them. The `[]` notation just let's the server-side engine know to expect multiple ones, so use a different data type.

Comment: Thank you.  It is really only for a little irrelevant education, so I could use it for future reference in Google searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no magic method to select elements in this manner, so some manual work is needed.

First of all, group elements by their name:

```
var buckets = {}; // keys: "name" attribute values, values: arrays of elements
$('[name$="[]"]').each(function() {
    var name = this.name,
        bucket = buckets[name] || (buckets[name] = []);
    bucket.push(this);
});
```

Then you can select the first element from each bucket and put it inside a jQuery object:

```
// start with an empty jQuery object
var $firstOfEach = $([]);

// add to the above the first element inside each bucket
$.each(buckets, function() { $firstOfEach = $firstOfEach.add(this[0]); });
```

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/RHyt5/)**.